# Open IE url in same window but new tab

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer

I want to open a few URLs in internet explorer. But I want to open them in same window but new tab. Not new window.

I am coding in VB.NET.

```
    Dim Start As New ProcessStartInfo
    Start.FileName = "iexplore.exe"
    Start.Arguments = "-private  " & "http://www.google.com"
    Process.Start(Start)
```

The above code open in new window. But I want all urls to open in same inprivate window but new tab. Window should be same and each url is a new tab in that window. I am running Windows 10 so IE11.

How can I do it ?

Comment: Perhaps you could run a PowerShell script? See: http://superuser.com/a/877249

Comment: It's not VB.NET, but I believe the same can be done in it: http://superuser.com/a/513985